# Command to insert information into optional settings of tikzcd environment

Tags: tikz-cd

I'd like to make a command to avoid writing `/tikz/column 1/.append style={anchor=base west}` every time. Is something like this possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\anchor}[2]{
    /tikz/column #1/.append style={anchor=#2}
}
\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzcd}[\anchor{1}{base west}]
        a
     \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros don't work when evaluating options.

I'd suggest using a style which does the same as you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

% \tikzset already adds /tikz as root
\tikzset{
  myanchor/.style 2 args={column #1/.append style={anchor=#2}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[myanchor={1}{base west}]
  a
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```